# conflict between positon:fixed and overflow:visible property in css

Tags: html, css

Here's the situation. I'm building a webpage where i position an image on the right side of the page. When I make the browser window smaller, i want horizontal scroll bars to appear, so i include overflow: visible property.  I also want the image to be positioned fixed so that when the page is scrolled down the content in the middle along with the background scrolls but the image stays as it is. But I am not able to bring both features to my page.The two properties seem to conflict each other. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too little.The problem of the front with the example of code.
try img fixed:

```
img.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 55;
}
```

Comment: Like this: `<img class="fixed" src="" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use css concept called media types....

you can not achieve this using only `position:fixed`

add this css to your page

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px), (max-height: 500px){
.overflowDiv{
         position:fixed;top:100px;height:100px;width:100px;
         overflow:scroll;
         }
```

change max-width and max-height according to your need

here is [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/87B6f/)

Hope it'll help you.

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. First off, I don't want a scroll bar just for that element, I want a scroll bar to appear for the complete page and overflow:scroll; doesn't have an effect.